# DrillUp Event not working for TreeMap - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a **TreeMap** with **drilldowns** in it. I wish to custom button to drillUp the Tree and found an event in Highchart (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.drillUp).

Sample Code that I tried - http://jsfiddle.net/vgnshs/t63xwxte/

I have placed a "Back" button below the Chart. When I click on it, in the console window of chrome I get this below error

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefinedm.drillUp @ drilldown.js:7(anonymous function) @ (index):990f.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3f.event.add.h.handle.i @ jquery.min.js:3"

Can you please help me if I am making any mistake or If there is some other approach to handle drill up in TreeMap?

Thanks.

```js
$(function () {
    var data = {        
        "Americas": {
            "Canada": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "318.0",
                "Injuries": "31.3",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "22.6"
            },
            "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "226.2",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "635.3",
                "Injuries": "100.0"
            },
            "Haiti": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "405.4",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "724.6",
                "Injuries": "89.3"
            },
            "Belize": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "470.7",
                "Injuries": "82.0",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "104.6"
            },
            "Suriname": {
                "Injuries": "70.5",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "83.7",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "374.8"
            },
            "Argentina": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "68.7",
                "Injuries": "50.7",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "467.3"
            },
            "Mexico": {
                "Injuries": "63.2",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "57.0",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "468.3"
            },
            "Jamaica": {
                "Injuries": "51.5",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "97.0",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "519.1"
            },
            "Peru": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "363.5",
                "Injuries": "47.9",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "121.3"
            },
            "Brazil": {
                "Injuries": "80.2",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "92.8",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "513.8"
            },
            "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "58.2",
                "Injuries": "103.2",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "410.6"
            },
            "Paraguay": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "485.5",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "77.3",
                "Injuries": "67.6"
            },
            "Chile": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "366.5",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "36.3",
                "Injuries": "41.2"
            },
            "Trinidad and Tobago": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "705.3",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "80.4",
                "Injuries": "98.4"
            },
            "Colombia": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "377.3",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "55.0",
                "Injuries": "72.6"
            },
            "Cuba": {
                "Injuries": "45.3",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "421.8",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "33.2"
            },
            "El Salvador": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "474.9",
                "Injuries": "157.7",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "96.2"
            },
            "Honduras": {
                "Injuries": "80.8",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "117.5",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "441.5"
            },
            "Ecuador": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "409.7",
                "Injuries": "83.7",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "97.3"
            },
            "Costa Rica": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "30.5",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "391.8",
                "Injuries": "46.5"
            },
            "Dominican Republic": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "396.0",
                "Injuries": "66.4",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "76.8"
            },
            "Nicaragua": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "75.2",
                "Injuries": "64.4",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "546.6"
            },
            "Barbados": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "404.5",
                "Injuries": "28.0",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "60.8"
            },
            "Uruguay": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "446.0",
                "Injuries": "53.8",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "46.2"
            },
            "Panama": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "86.1",
                "Injuries": "67.4",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "372.9"
            },
            "Bahamas": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "465.2",
                "Injuries": "45.7",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "122.0"
            },
            "Guyana": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "177.2",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "1024.2",
                "Injuries": "150.0"
            },
            "United States of America": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "412.8",
                "Injuries": "44.2",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "31.3"
            },
            "Guatemala": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "212.7",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "409.4",
                "Injuries": "111.0"
            }
        },
        "Eastern Mediterranean": {
            "Egypt": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "74.3",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "781.7",
                "Injuries": "33.5"
            },
            "South Sudan": {
                "Injuries": "143.4",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "831.3",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "623.4"
            },
            "Sudan": {
                "Injuries": "133.6",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "551.0",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "495.0"
            },
            "Libya": {
                "Injuries": "62.8",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "550.0",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "52.6"
            },
            "Jordan": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "640.3",
                "Injuries": "53.5",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "52.5"
            },
            "Pakistan": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "296.0",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "669.3",
                "Injuries": "98.7"
            },
            "Djibouti": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "631.1",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "626.0",
                "Injuries": "106.0"
            },
            "Syrian Arab Republic": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "41.0",
                "Injuries": "308.0",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "572.7"
            },
            "Morocco": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "707.7",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "131.5",
                "Injuries": "47.0"
            },
            "Yemen": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "515.0",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "626.9",
                "Injuries": "84.3"
            },
            "Bahrain": {
                "Injuries": "33.5",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "505.7",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "48.5"
            },
            "United Arab Emirates": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "546.8",
                "Injuries": "31.5",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "35.6"
            },
            "Lebanon": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "384.6",
                "Injuries": "40.6",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "30.5"
            },
            "Saudi Arabia": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "549.4",
                "Injuries": "41.1",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "71.3"
            },
            "Iran (Islamic Republic of)": {
                "Injuries": "74.9",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "56.2",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "569.3"
            },
            "Iraq": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "87.0",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "715.5",
                "Injuries": "128.5"
            },
            "Qatar": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "28.3",
                "Injuries": "41.0",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "407.0"
            },
            "Afghanistan": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "362.7",
                "Injuries": "169.2",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "846.3"
            },
            "Somalia": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "550.7",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "927.2",
                "Injuries": "188.5"
            },
            "Kuwait": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "82.5",
                "Injuries": "25.4",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "406.3"
            },
            "Oman": {
                "Injuries": "52.8",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "478.2",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "84.2"
            },
            "Tunisia": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "509.3",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "65.0",
                "Injuries": "39.1"
            }
        },
        "Western Pacific": {
            "Mongolia": {
                "Injuries": "69.4",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "966.5",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "82.8"
            },
            "Cambodia": {
                "Injuries": "62.2",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "227.5",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "394.0"
            },
            "Japan": {
                "Injuries": "40.5",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "244.2",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "33.9"
            },
            "Brunei Darussalam": {
                "Injuries": "44.6",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "475.3",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "56.1"
            },
            "Solomon Islands": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "230.6",
                "Injuries": "75.1",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "709.7"
            },
            "Viet Nam": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "96.0",
                "Injuries": "59.0",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "435.4"
            },
            "Lao People's Democratic Republic": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "328.7",
                "Injuries": "75.2",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "680.0"
            },
            "China": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "41.4",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "576.3",
                "Injuries": "50.4"
            },
            "New Zealand": {
                "Injuries": "32.9",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "313.6",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "18.0"
            },
            "Papua New Guinea": {
                "Injuries": "100.1",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "554.3",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "693.2"
            },
            "Philippines": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "226.4",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "720.0",
                "Injuries": "53.8"
            },
            "Malaysia": {
                "Injuries": "62.8",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "563.2",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "117.4"
            },
            "Australia": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "13.7",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "302.9",
                "Injuries": "28.2"
            },
            "Fiji": {
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "804.0",
                "Injuries": "64.0",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "105.2"
            },
            "Singapore": {
                "Communicable & other Group I": "66.2",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "264.8",
                "Injuries": "17.5"
            },
            "Republic of Korea": {
                "Injuries": "53.1",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "33.8",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "302.1"
            }
        }
    },
        points = [],
        region_p,
        region_val,
        region_i,
        country_p,
        country_i,
        cause_p,
        cause_i,
        cause_name = [],
        region,
        country,
        cause;
    cause_name['Communicable & other Group I'] = 'Communicable diseases';
    cause_name['Noncommunicable diseases'] = 'Non-communicable diseases';
    cause_name.Injuries = 'Injuries';
    region_i = 0;
    for (region in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(region)) {
            region_val = 0;
            region_p = {
                id: "id_" + region_i,
                name: region,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[region_i]
            };
            country_i = 0;
            for (country in data[region]) {
                if (data[region].hasOwnProperty(country)) {
                    country_p = {
                        id: region_p.id + "_" + country_i,
                        name: country,
                        parent: region_p.id
                    };
                    points.push(country_p);
                    cause_i = 0;
                    for (cause in data[region][country]) {
                        if (data[region][country].hasOwnProperty(cause)) {
                            cause_p = {
                                id: country_p.id + "_" + cause_i,
                                name: cause_name[cause],
                                parent: country_p.id,
                                value: Math.round(+data[region][country][cause])
                            };
                            region_val += cause_p.value;
                            points.push(cause_p);
                            cause_i = cause_i + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    country_i = country_i + 1;
                }
            }
            region_p.value = Math.round(region_val / country_i);
            points.push(region_p);
            region_i = region_i + 1;
        }
    }
  var options ={    
        credits: {
            enabled: false   
        },
        chart: {
            borderColor: '#EBBA95',
            borderWidth: 2,           
            renderTo : "container"
        },
        series: [{
            type: "treemap",
            layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
            allowDrillToNode: true,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            levelIsConstant: false,
            levels: [{
                level: 1,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                borderWidth: 1
            }],
            data: points
        }],
        title: {
            text: "Sample Tree"
        }
    };
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);   
    
    $('#iClick').click(function(){
        chart1.drillUp();
    });

});
```

```css
#container {
 min-width: 300px;
 max-width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div><br/><br/>
<input id="iClick" type ="submit" value="Back"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for reporting, looks like a bug: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4383

Comment: Hi Sebastian. I feel like that bug is closed saying "Its not a bug". In that case, Is there any way I can have custom button and handle DrillDown / DrillUp during My own button's click on TreeMap?